# no ultimately trusted keys found when instaling Sublime 3 on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, apt, xubuntu, ppa, sublime-text

I am trying to install Sublime 3 in Ubuntu 14.04

I am getting below error after running command `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/sublime-text-3`

```
gpg: keyring `/tmp/tmpegw5gk2n/secring.gpg' created
gpg: keyring `/tmp/tmpegw5gk2n/pubring.gpg' created
gpg: requesting key EEA14886 from hkp server keyserver.ubuntu.com
gpg: /tmp/tmpegw5gk2n/trustdb.gpg: trustdb created
gpg: key EEA14886: public key "Launchpad VLC" imported
gpg: no ultimately trusted keys found
gpg: Total number processed: 1
gpg:               imported: 1  (RSA: 1)
OK
```

I searched for solution and someone posted this

`sudo add-apt-repository ppa:nilarimogard/webupd8`
This gave me following message

```
gpg: keyring `/tmp/tmpvys_6icc/secring.gpg' created
gpg: keyring `/tmp/tmpvys_6icc/pubring.gpg' created
gpg: requesting key 4C9D234C from hkp server keyserver.ubuntu.com
gpg: /tmp/tmpvys_6icc/trustdb.gpg: trustdb created
gpg: key 4C9D234C: public key "Launchpad webupd8" imported
gpg: Total number processed: 1
gpg:               imported: 1  (RSA: 1)
OK
```

`sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install launchpad-getkey`

But I still have same error.

Comment: Did you ever establish any "web of trust"?  Trust is up to you, not the keys.

Comment: sorry what that means? I had ubuntu 12 and I was able to install sublime 2 in that ... now I have ubuntu 14 and I am getting this error

Comment: It's not an error, just information that you have never set any trust information on your keys.

Comment: what is solution?

Answer (score 0):

I assume the install of Sublime 3 succeeded, since this key trust would not affect that.  You can simply ignore the trust issue, it's not a new thing, but maybe the software is now noting the fact that you never set any degree of trust on your keys.  To set trust on your keys, you should read about the whole web of trust concept and decide what level of trust to apply to your keys and other's signatures.
https://www.gnupg.org/gph/en/manual/x334.html
It's entirely up to you -- you decide if you trust a key, and you decide if you trust someone else's indication of trust on a key.